# Nginx confusing $fastcgi_script_name with $fastcgi_path_info

Tags: url, nginx, configuration, configuration-files, fastcgi

Here is the relevant part of my Nginx configuration file:

```
http {
    log_format  fastcgi
                '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$fastcgi_script_name" "$fastcgi_path_info"';

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log  fastcgi;

        location / {
            fastcgi_index /;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/var/www/run/httpd.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have a Unix socket at `/usr/local/var/www/run/httpd.sock` which handles FastCGI requests, and it works quite well. The problem here is that Nginx thinks the last part of the URI is the script name, but it should be the path info. For example

```
⇒ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.0
⇒ nginx
⇒ curl -i localhost:8080/index
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.0
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2018 12:27:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

<p>hello, world</p>
⇒ tail -n 1 /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2018:20:27:15 +0800] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 30 "-" "/index" ""
```

This means `$fastcgi_script_name` is `/index`, with `$fastcgi_script_name` being an empty string.

How can I configure Nginx to make `$fastcgi_script_name` to contain the last part of a URI, i.e. things like `/index`?

Comment: `$fastcgi_path_info` is set using the `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive (see [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info)). By default, `$fastcgi_script_name` is the same as `$uri`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard Smith has pointed out in their comment, you have to parse the path info by configuring [`fastcgi_split_path_info`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info).

For example, in this case you'll want

```
location / {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^()(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/usr/local/var/www/run/httpd.sock;
    include  fastcgi_params;
}
```